# What are the variables accessible from user_mailer.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

My user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "notifications@example.com"
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "http://example.com/login"
    mail(:to => user.email,:subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site") do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

And this is how my user_mailer.html.erb looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>   
    <%= yield %> 
  </body>
</html>
```

What can I access in user_mailer.html.erb.
Where do I need to define environment variables so that I can access it here ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you took your example from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)?

You can treat `user_mailer.html.erb` like a view, and `user_mailer.rb` like its controller. So if you've defined an instance variable `@users` then you can use that in the mail. As per the example in the link:

user_mailer.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.login %>.<br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also use helpers, so no reason to hardcode a URL in like that, instead you could use `sign_in_url` (or whatever route you have for the login path).

Note that in email you should always use `something_url` rather than `something_path` (so `root_url` etc.)

You should define your variables in the `welcome_email` method:

```
def welcome_email(user)
  @user = user
  @time = Time.now
  @slogan = "My App's slogan"
  ...
  mail(:to => user.email,:subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site") do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any instance variable in the view part. So in your case,

```
 @user and @url are accessible in user_mailer.html.erb
```